# Russian doll envelops

Tags: python, optimization, interview-questions, complexity

Interview question from the interwebz

> *You have a set of envelopes of different widths and heights.  One
>   envelope can fit into another if and only if both the width and height
>   of one envelope is greater than the width and height of the other
>   envelope. What is the maximum number of envelopes can you russian
>   doll?*

My implementation:

```
# assuming no dups
def max_russian_doll(enve):
    if not enve: return 0
    enve.sort()
    max_global = 1
    for j in xrange(len(enve) - 1):
        max_local = 1
        for i in xrange(j, len(enve) - 1):
            if enve[i][1] < enve[i + 1][1] and enve[i][0] != enve[i + 1][0]: # @comment 
                max_local += 1
        max_global = max(max_global, max_local)    
    return max_global

envelopes = [(4,5), (6,7), (2,3)]  
max_russian_doll(envelopes)
```

obviously this is \$O(n^2)\$. Right now I'm trying to figure out faster solution. Any tips?

Comment: `envelopes.sort()` looks out-of-place.... should that be `enve.sort()`?

Comment: do you have some more test cases ?

Comment: @rolfl yes! I just had the text. I made up the test case. My first observation is that we repeat some comparisons. Can we cache that? Dynamic programming?

Comment: Your algorithm does not handle the case where the first elements of the tuples are same: `max_russian_doll([(4,5), (4,6), (6,7), (2,3)] )` is `4`. But `(4,5)` and `(4,6)` can't be both counted by the definition.

Comment: Now, if you had somehow handled the repeating widths, the question turns to a [Longest increasing subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) after sorting according to widths, which has **O(n log n)** complexity, which you should probably shoot for.

Answer (score 3):

Using [LIS from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence).

```
def max_russian_doll(seq):
    if not seq: return 0
    seq.sort()
    M = [0] * (len(seq) + 1)
    L = 1
    for i in xrange(len(seq)):
        lo = 1
        hi = L
        while lo <= hi:
            mid = (hi - lo)/2 + lo
            if seq[M[mid]][1] < seq[i][1] and seq[M[mid]][0] < seq[i][0]:
                lo = mid + 1
            else:
                hi = mid - 1
        newL = lo
        if newL > L:
            M[newL] = i
            L = newL
    return L

print max_russian_doll([]) == 0
print max_russian_doll([(1,1)]) == 1 
print max_russian_doll([(1,1), (1,1), (1,1)]) == 1
print max_russian_doll([(4,5), (4,6), (6,7), (2,3), (1,1)]) == 4 # e.g (1,1) -> (2,3) -> (4,5) -> (6,7)
print max_russian_doll([(4,5), (4,6), (6,7), (2,3), (1,1), (1,1)]) == 4
print max_russian_doll([(5,4), (6,4), (6,7), (2,3)]) == 3
```

Comment: Gives wrong result for: `[(1,100),(2,200),(3,300),(4,400),(4,250),(5,300),(6,350)]`